# jQuery: Simulate button click animation

Tags: jquery, animation, button, triggers, click

I am trying to simulate a search button paired with a text box.  Right now, I have it set up such that when you hit "enter" in the text box, it will call the jQuery `trigger` function and call the search button's `click` event handler.  However, I was wondering if I could also make it so that hitting "enter" in the text box triggers the button's click animation.  Is there any way to do this?

Here is some of my code:

```
$("#" + button).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $("#" + button + "_searchButton").trigger("click");
    }
});

$("#" + button + "_searchButton").click(function() { searchFilter(); });
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: If you are triggering code to execute the click function, then why can't you just add your animation code to that?

Comment: I was wondering if there is any way to call the default animation for a button, as opposed to adding my own animation.  I would imagine that adding my own animation would require me to find the image as well?

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
$("button").click()
```

To make a click event